# One login for 3 WordPress installations with combined user table doesn't work

Tags: multisite, login, shared-user-tables

I have 3 WordPress installations with combined user/user_meta tables and I want to share logins with all WordPress installations. One installation is stored in the **root directory** and two others in **subdirectories**. Everything is done according to the rules (I think).

This is code in `wp-config.php file`:

```
define('AUTH_KEY','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('NONCE_KEY','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('AUTH_SALT','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT','somesting'); // like in another configs
define('NONCE_SALT','somesting'); // like in another configs
$table_prefix  = 'w2_'; // prefix is different

define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'abs_users'); // like in another configs
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'abs_usermeta'); // like in another configs

$baseurl = 'http://example.com/'; // domain where root wordpress installation is stored, like in another configs
$cookiehash = md5($baseurl);  // like in another configs
define('COOKIEHASH', $cookiehash);  // like in another configs
define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_'.COOKIEHASH);  // like in another configs
define('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_sec_'.COOKIEHASH);  // like in another configs
define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE','wordpress_logged_in_'.COOKIEHASH);  // like in another configs
define('TEST_COOKIE', 'wordpress_test_cookie');  // like in another configs

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');  // like in another configs
define('COOKIEPATH', '/'); // like in another configs

define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');  // like in another configs
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');  // like in another configs
```

I log in to one admin panel and get some cookie files like a: **wordpress_...** and **wordpress_logged_in_...**. Next I go into another admin panel and again see login page, my cookie is deleted and I'm logged out of first admin panel.

What I do wrong?

Version 4.3.1

**UPD:**
All works fine and session sharing for all sites if i login in new browser first time. After i logout problem occur again in new browser. 
Deleting all cookie not helped.

Comment: It's not enough to share the user table, can you provide more information on the sites themselves? What's their URL structure? Are these subdomains? Sub directories? What was your reasoning for not just using a multisite install which would give you the shared login you wanted?

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply use a WP multi-site install using the sub-domain option?  Seems like an obvious use case.

Comment: Sites uses subdirectories, like http://example.com/, http://example.com/en, http://example.com/uk
I can't use multisite option because that sites work for a long time and have a lot of their own content.

Comment: Oh...god. All worked fine. Problem was in &reauth=1 parameter, when i logout from one wordpress, others wordpress redirected me to url with this parameter and i logged out again. Question closed.

Comment: Each site in a multisite install can have its own content too, you just need to migrate it